# C# - Cannot implicitly convert type 'IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2DataReader' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader'

Tags: c#, sql, db2, ibm-midrange, ranorex

I am working in a Ranorex project, but it isn't a Ranorex specific problem. I need to open a connection to an AS400 DB2 Database and then run a SQL query against it.

I have code that successfully opens the connection and returns the results of the SQL query.

```
iDB2Connection cn = new iDB2Connection("Data Source=as400_DB;User ID=CLIENT;Password=CLIENT;Default Collection=XXXXXX;Naming=System");
 cn.Open();
 iDB2Command cmd = new iDB2Command("select count(*) from ABC_table where xxxx = 'WC' AND xxxx = 'L302328'", cn);
 int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
 Report.Log(ReportLevel.Info, "count", count.ToString());
 cn.Close();
```

In the code, the second method, calls the first method to open the connection, which then allows the second method to run the SQL commands, but I get the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2DataReader'
>   to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader'

at the 'return new iDB2Connection(cn.ToString())' point in the first method.

```
    public static class sQlHelper
{
    private static SqlConnection sQlConnect()
    {   

            iDB2Connection cn = new iDB2Connection("Data Source=as400_DB;User ID=CLIENT;Password=CLIENT;Default Collection=XXXXXX;Naming=System");

            return new iDB2Connection(cn.ToString());

    }

    public static void validateResult()
    {
            var myConnection = sQlConnect();
            myConnection.Open();

            string sqlStatementForCheckHeaders = "select count(*) from ABC_table where xxxx = 'WC' AND xxxx = 'L302328'";
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

            SqlDataReader myReader = null;
            iDB2Command myCommand = new iDB2Command(sqlStatementForCheckHeaders, myConnection);
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while(myReader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myReader["Column1"].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(myReader["Column2"].ToString());
            }

            myConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

I can't workout how to resolve the issue and I have not been able to find any information on the error itself. I would be grateful for any support/advice people can supply.

Comment: Your method _sQlConnect_ is a bit redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two flaws in that code. I think you are confusing `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace with `IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries`.

First, your `sQlConnect` method is declared to return a `SqlConnection`, but returns an `iDB2Connection` instead. Fix the signature:

```
private static iDB2Connection sQlConnect() // returns a IDB2Connection!
{   
    return new iDB2Connection("Data Source=as400_DB;User ID=CLIENT;Password=CLIENT;Default Collection=XXXXXX;Naming=System");
}
```

The second error message is caused by the wrong declaration of `myReader`. Since `myCommand` is an `iDB2Command` (and *not* a `SqlCommand`), its `ExecuteReader()` method returns a `IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2DataReader`, and not a `SqlDataReader`.

So you just need to change your declaration of `myReader`:

```
 iDB2Command myCommand = new iDB2Command(sqlStatementForCheckHeaders, myConnection);
 // use the correct type (or var)
 iDB2DataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
 while(myReader.Read()) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, for your help. I have now managed to open the connector, but need to work on the SQL that comes in the second method.

Answer (score 1):

**First** thing to do , Update your method definition to return `iDB2Connection` instead of `SQLConnection`

```
 private static iDB2Connection sQlConnect()
 { 
        return new iDB2Connection("Data Source=as400_DB;User ID=CLIENT;Password=CLIENT;Default Collection=XXXXXX;Naming=System");

 }
```

**Secondly**

`cmd.ExecuteScalar();` cannot be cast to an `iDB2DataReader` - you are trying to return a single value not a datareader so use something like

```
int hasRecords = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Thanks, for your help. I have now managed to open the connector, but need to work on the SQL that comes in the second method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to be able to tag both replies as the correct answer, but both the post from René Vogt and Ehsan Ullah Nazir provided the solution to my question. Thanks to both of you.